# ChannelUrl does not load at all

Tags: facebook

According to [Facebook's documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/), I put `channelUrl: '//www.my-domain.com/fb_channel'` inside `FB.init()`. However, I could not see `www.my-domain.com/fb_channel` got loaded at all with Firefox and Chrome's network inspector.

Is this normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly normal. The reason you need the `channelUrl` is for cross-domain communication between your domain and FBs; it uses a nested IFRAME to communicate. However, in newer browsers you can use `window.postMessage`, which is more performant so the `channelUrl` is not used in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

The contents of the channel file is a single line

```
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

So if there is something wrong, it's something in your server that is not loading the file properly.

Comment: I mean, the browser is not requesting `www.my-domain.com/fb_channel` at all. Not even related to the content in that URL. The code inside `window.fbAsyncInit` did run, so I can see `//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js` attached to DOM.